# How many UIViews can be displayed simultaneously on iOS before running into performance problems?

Tags: iphone, performance, ios, animation, uiview

I'm making an iPhone game and using `UIView` objects to draw sprites.  Most of the time, I have no performance problems.  However, once I have around 15 to 20 objects on the screen (and maybe 5 of them moving around), the game becomes considerably slower, especially on the iPhone 3G.  The frame rate can drop to as low as a single frame per second.

Is this simply a limitation of using `UIView` objects, or should iOS be able to handle this many `UIView` objects on screen at the same time?

In order to isolate the problem, I've made drawing my views very simple — drawing a red rectangle.  `drawRect` is only getting called once per view.  The view hierarchy is very simple and shallow.  I'm using `CADisplayLink` to update the `UIView` locations every frame.

There's very little else going on, so I'd like to hear if anyone else has had success using this number of `UIView` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to my problems ended up being that I had labels on top of my game content.  The labels are not opaque, which likely was a large part of the problem, as phix23 suggested.

The first thing that made a big difference was removing a frames per second label that was on top of the content.  Having a label that changed content on every frame caused a lot of slowdown.

I also had a large label that displayed on top of much of the game and changed shape when you level up.  It turned out that drawing this label on top of everything caused a lot of slowdown as well.

In answer to my original question, I've found that on an iPhone 3G I can support about 30-40 opaque UIViews onscreen at the same time, with 2 or 3 non-opaque views as well.  Non-opaque UIViews that change size, shape, or location are by far the worst, and even one of these that covers a significant amount of the screen can quickly cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

If you're setting the `opaque` property of each view to `NO`, keep in mind that this seriously affects the speed of drawing the views. If your views aren't transparent, you should leave this set to `YES`, which is default.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything has opaque set to YES, so I don't think this is the problem.  Although I've heard others say that opaqueness can make a big difference, in my own tests I haven't seen opaque make any noticeable difference, so I suspect that something else is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

for such type of application you should use CoreGraphics / Quartz / OpenGL but anyway I don't think there is a limitation on such low count. For example if I have a table view with 9 rows and each row has 5 subviews its still displayed acceptable fast. Have you tried using UIView animation to change the position in view?

good luck in learning OpenGL ;)

Comment: I'm gathering that that's the case, although I'm hoping to avoid a big overhaul to change drawing systems at this point. =/

I have tried to use UIView animation, and it seems to help, but there are some pretty difficult limitations to get around such as not being able to stop mid-animation, and not being able to access the interpolated property values.

Comment: but you can set the animationFromCurrentState to YES and it will continue the new animation from the old state

Comment: True, but I also need to be able to touch the UIView and have it respond while the animation is happening.  During the animation of a UIView it won't respond at its currently-animated location, it will respond to touch events at its final destination.